# Creating Bison File for Simple Grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, bison, yacc

I have the following simple grammar:

```
E -> T | ^ v . E 
T -> F T1 
T1 -> F T1 | epsilon
F -> ( E ) | v
```

I'm pretty new to Bison, so I was hoping someone could help show me how to write it out in that format. All I have so far is the following, but I'm not sure if it's correct:

```
 %left '.'
 %left 'v'
 %% /* The grammar follows.  */

 exp:
 term               {printf("1");}
 | '^' 'v' '.' exp  {printf("2");}
 ;

 term:
 factor term1       {printf("3");}
 ;

 term1:
 factor term1       {printf("4");}
 |                  {printf("5");}      
 ;

 factor:
 '(' exp ')'        {printf("6");}
 | 'v'              {printf("7");}
 ;
 %%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing semicolon from several of the productions. There's nothing in the source grammar to suggest you need the productions about lines.

Comment: You're right about the semicolons, but I think Bison fixed that for me during compilation - the .output file was the same before and after. Good point about the lines though. Does everything else match up?

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if you could also tell me if to produce the .output file, the %left rules at the top matter or not.

Comment: They matter but again there's nothing in the source grammar that tells you whether they are left-associative or not. On the other hand most operators except exponentiation are left-associative, so it's a good guess. But for coursework I would leave them out unless doing so introduces ambiguities, which bison will tell you about. Are they the Pascal operators for dereferencing and record-membership?

Comment: I didn't specify it in the question, but this is a grammar for lambda calculus, and one of the requirements is that 'v' is left associative and that it binds tighter than '.'. I am a bit confused by the terminology "binds tighter than" to be honest, but I assume it means that it has higher precedence.

Comment: In that case the source grammar is wrong, as it gives them both the same precedence. Sort that out first. Don't confuse associativity with precedence.

Comment: I thought placing an associativity rule below another rule implied higher precedence, no?

Comment: Ahem, yes it does, oops, it's been a while :-|